# XMonad remap caps lock to escape

Tags: xmonad

I was using Gnome but when I switched to XMonad the escape to caps lock remapping I created does not work. I am not sure how to configure XMonad to do this swap.
I tried
`xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = Escape NoSymbol Escape"` and `xmodmap -e "keycode 9  = Caps_Lock NoSymbol Caps_Lock"` and used `xev` to confirm that `9` and `66` where indeed the correct keycodes. However both escape and caps lock now toggle caps lock and neither toggles escape.

Comment: Can you [edit your question](http://superuser.com/posts/964732/edit) to include what you've tried for the Capslock escape? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = Escape"
xmodmap -e "keycode 9  = Caps_Lock"
xmodmap -e "clear Lock"
```